# Suggestion for separation of CSS from XLST files

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt, xls

I just like to ask for advice on how to improve the way i write my XSLT file. I would also like to ask if anyone knows how to separate CSS files dedicated for the use of XSLT files. Any advice would be a great help to me Thanks in advance guys.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
     <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

     <xsl:template match="/">
       <html>
         <head>
           <title>This is my tes application</title>
           <style type="text/css">
             body
             {
             /*Background Properties*/
             background-color:#b0c4de;

             /*Font Properties*/
             font-family:Arial;
             font-size:14px;
             }

             .TitleStyle
             {
             /*Text Properties*/
             text-align:left;

             /*Font Properties*/
             font-size:24;

             /*Layout Properties*/
             margin-bottom: 5px;
             }

             .Wrapper
             {
             padding: 5px;
             border-width:2px;
             border-style:solid;
             }

             .WhiteHeader
             {
             color:white;
             }

             .ProviderStyle
             {
             font-size:18px;
             }

           </style>
         </head>
         <body>
           <xsl:for-each select="JobRequistions/JobRequisition">
             <hr />
             <div class="Wrapper">
               <div class="TitleStyle">
                 <font class="WhiteHeader">
                   <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="title" />
                 </font>
                 <font class="ProviderStyle">
                   @ <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="job_board_provider"/>
                 </font>
               </div>
               Number of openings: <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="number_of_openings"/>
               <hr />
             </div>
             <hr />
           </xsl:for-each >
         </body>
       </html>
     </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why are you using non-standard msxsl?

Comment: Im' sorry but i dont even know what is the difference between non-standard from the standard one. its my first day buddy forgive me :)

Comment: The msxsl stuff is proprietary to Microsoft and non-standard. Unless you know you need or that, I'd remove those two proprietaries from your stylesheet declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is natural and almost trivial even in XSLT 1.0**.

It is most natural to keep the `<style>` element and all of its descendants in another, separate XML file. The filepath to this separate file can be passed as a parameter to the transformation -- thus fully configurable:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
     <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

     <xsl:param name="pStylefilePath" select="'somedefaultUrl'"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vStyle"
          select="document($pStylefilePath)"/>

     <xsl:template match="/">
       <html>
         <head>
           <title>This is my tes application</title>
           <xsl:copy-of select="$vStyle/*"/>
         </head>
         <body>
           <xsl:for-each select="JobRequistions/JobRequisition">
             <hr />
             <div class="Wrapper">
               <div class="TitleStyle">
                 <font class="WhiteHeader">
                   <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="title" />
                 </font>
                 <font class="ProviderStyle">
                   @ <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="job_board_provider"/>
                 </font>
               </div>
               Number of openings: <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="number_of_openings"/>
               <hr />
             </div>
             <hr />
           </xsl:for-each >
         </body>
       </html>
     </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**You may even go further** and put the whole XHTML skeletal text (the XHTML with special elements that will be matched and processed by the transformation and will be substituted by the results of this processing) in a separate file -- the so called "fill in the blanks" technique.

In this case you also will have another filepath parameter -- the path to the XHTML skeleton.

**Here is a simple, complete example** (using a dummy source XML document as you haven't shown the real one):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
     <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

     <xsl:param name="pStylefilePath"
     select="'file:///c:/temp/delete/style.xml'"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vStyle"
          select="document($pStylefilePath)"/>

     <xsl:template match="/">
       <html>
         <head>
           <title>This is my tes application</title>
           <xsl:copy-of select="$vStyle/*"/>
         </head>
         <body>
           <xsl:for-each select="JobRequistions/JobRequisition">
             <hr />
             <div class="Wrapper">
               <div class="TitleStyle">
                 <font class="WhiteHeader">
                   <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="title" />
                 </font>
                 <font class="ProviderStyle">
                   @ <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="job_board_provider"/>
                 </font>
               </div>
               Number of openings: <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="number_of_openings"/>
               <hr />
             </div>
             <hr />
           </xsl:for-each >
         </body>
       </html>
     </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The file: `c:/temp/delete/style.xml` is just your `<style>` element**:

```
<style type="text/css">
             body
             {
             /*Background Properties*/
             background-color:#b0c4de;

             /*Font Properties*/
             font-family:Arial;
             font-size:14px;
             }

             .TitleStyle
             {
             /*Text Properties*/
             text-align:left;

             /*Font Properties*/
             font-size:24;

             /*Layout Properties*/
             margin-bottom: 5px;
             }

             .Wrapper
             {
             padding: 5px;
             border-width:2px;
             border-style:solid;
             }

             .WhiteHeader
             {
             color:white;
             }

             .ProviderStyle
             {
             font-size:18px;
             }

</style>
```

When the transformation above is applied on any XML document (not used), like this one:

```
<t/>
```

**The wanted result is produced**:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

      <title>This is my tes application</title><style type="text/css">
             body
             {
             /*Background Properties*/
             background-color:#b0c4de;

             /*Font Properties*/
             font-family:Arial;
             font-size:14px;
             }

             .TitleStyle
             {
             /*Text Properties*/
             text-align:left;

             /*Font Properties*/
             font-size:24;

             /*Layout Properties*/
             margin-bottom: 5px;
             }

             .Wrapper
             {
             padding: 5px;
             border-width:2px;
             border-style:solid;
             }

             .WhiteHeader
             {
             color:white;
             }

             .ProviderStyle
             {
             font-size:18px;
             }

</style></head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre, Thanks for the idea this would help allot. If you don't mind can you show me how could I store the style in another XML file even a small code snippet will do :)

Comment: @AllanChua: You physically cut the `<style>...</style>` text from your current stylesheet and then save this (paste) into a new file anywhere in the file system. Then specify the file URL for this new file as the value of the `$ppStylefilePath` in the transformation in my answe. Then off you go :)

Comment: @AllanChua: I updated my answer and now you'll see at the end a complete example that you may easily run yourself -- to get a better feeling/idea.

Comment: Gee thanks for the help buddy this would help allot to me :) THIS IS CRAZY MEN its working :) thanks again :)

Comment: Uhmm another thing buddy :) can i ask what is the use of the $ sign in "document($pStylefilePath)"?

Comment: @AllanChua: This is something very basic in XSLT. Variable names and parameter names are represented inside any XPath expression by prepending a "$" character in front of the name. Thus in an XPath expression `$employee` means the variable named `"employee"` and not the children of the context node that are named `"employee"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use an external stylesheet the same way you do in html by just adding a link in the head.

Comment: How about XHTML buddy? can i also add it in the XSLT file?

Comment: Of course but I'm confused. You are showing XHTML but haven't declared that namespace yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull in external text using unparsed-text (and unparsed-text-available to check for the file). It's XSLT 2.0 only, though.

Comment: Sorry :-) It's an XSLT function. Its signature is unparsed-text($href as xs:string?) as xs:string?. The href refers to an external file, and the result is the file's contents as a string. It need not be an XML file, it will work for CSS, too.

Comment: Then you can write out the string with xsl:value-of, or store it in a variable for later processing.

Comment: <head><title>This is my test application</title><style type="text/css"><xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text('my.css')"/></style></head>

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to add a link to a css file like that :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="html" encoding="utf-8"
doctype-public="HTML" doctype-system=""/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
     <head>
       <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" />
       <title>This is my tes application</title>
       ...
     </head>
     <body>
```

You just have to create "mystyle.css" file on the same folder of your xsl file 
I did some xsl files with external javascript and css file. It works fine for me